# Google Analytics code not working on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

We have a Wordpress site that has been running GA code fine for years. We noticed recently it had stopped reporting and that GA reports the code is not installed. The code is clearly there in the page source - I have tried sticking it directly into the code in the head and in the footer, I have tried using the theme to insert it and thirdparty plug-ins - nothing works.

I have tried changing the theme to the standard WP theme, I have tried turning off plug-ins one at a time (might try turning all off at once tonight!). I have tried removing the .htaccess file.

It feels like something is blocking it but can't figure out what.

Looking at the date of when it stopped working I think it is around the time we upgraded the PHP version of the server but not sure how this would have affected it and there are other Wordpress installs on the same server that are still collecting GA data perfectly happily!

Any advice welcome this is driving me insane now! Site can be viewed here: goo.gl/UO6deJ - Sorry if this has already been covered but everything else I read seemed to be related to plugins not functioning as they should.

Comment: I see you have 2 instances of google analytics in the code. One is enough. Anyway, you could verify that the analytics code ( including all the javascript part ) is exactly the same as given by google in your account details.

Comment: Unfortunately just after I posted this, the client in his infinite wisdom thought he'd cracked it and inserted the code in again! And yes it is an exact copy and paste of ALL code from GA.

Answer (score 0):

As @Fazz mentioned, you have two instances of the same code which would duplicate all your data and skew your results. Also, you can check your Real-Time reports to see if you are tracking your own visits simultaneously. If you can see hits in your RT reports, then likely your tracking code is good. You can also install Google Tag Assistant to help diagnose any other issues with your tracking code.

Can you check to see if you were migrated from classic GA to UA? Usually you should wait 48 hours from initial installation before seeing data in your standard reports (but you should still see data in RT).